# Python Selenium - open more Chrome apps

Tags: selenium

I'm using Selenium to automate certain stuff in Chrome and I know how to open multiple tabs, but is it possible to open Chrome itself multiple times?

Right now, when I want to open a new Chrome app the old one closes. I want it to stay open.

Answer (score 0):

every time you want to open a new Chrome Browser you have to create a new instance of the `webdriver`.

```py
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver

fist_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver")
fist_driver.get("https://google.com")
second_driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/chromedriver")
second_driver.get("https://ifconfig.me")
sleep(5)
# using for loop
for _ in range(2): # How much browser you want to open
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/path/to/driver")
    driver.get("https://google.com")
sleep(5)
```

Comment: Okay got it, and is it possible to do this in a loop as well? If yes, how?

Comment: @GaneshGebhard Yes, you can check the edited code above.

Comment: The code without the for-loop works perfectly, but with the for-loop not: the already opened browser closes first and then the new one opens. Hence only one browser is opened eventually.

Comment: @GaneshGebhard I forgot to add a sleep statement check the edited code again.

Comment: Nope, doesn't seem to work. I put 'sleep' inside the for loop (since I think that is what you meant), but the first window closes the moment the second window opens.